# SQL Server: Convert YYYYMMDD-HHMM and YYYYMMDD to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert the time format from `YYYYMMDD-HHMM` and `YYYYMMDD` to `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`. My issue is that the data is not consistent. Below is some exemple:

```
20200814-1230
20200814-1230
20200814     
20200814
```

I tried to use:

```
    CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(id,8),120) + ' ' +  
    LEFT(RIGHT(ID , 6) ,2) + ':' + 
    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(ID , 6) , 3,2),
```

but the issue is that some data does not have time.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Date/datetime values in databases aren't stored as strings and they don't have "formats" - formatting date/datetime values should only be performed by your user-facing UI code, not SQL.

Comment: What should the time-of-day component be for a date-only string like `'20200814'`? Is it correct to convert it to `'2020-08-14 00:00'`?

Comment: Regarding my first comment: it looks like your database is storing date/datetime values in the `id` column as text - is it possible to redesign your database to _not do that_? Or can you do the conversion in application code (i.e. outside of SQL)?

Comment: Hi Dai - I totally agree with your view, but I have no idea why our database is setup as such and it is not up to me to change it. I am trying to clean the data up for visualization purpose.  To be honest i would think that the end-user has been too lazy to type in the time, thus the time is mising, but yes the best assumption would be to covert '20200814' to '2020-08-14 00:0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
declare @dt varchar(100) = '20200814-1230'

select 
  substring(@dt, 5,2) + '/' +
  substring(@dt, 7,2) + '/' +
  substring(@dt, 1,4) +
  case
    when len(@dt) > 8 then
      ' ' +
      substring(@dt, 10,2) + ':' +
      substring(@dt, 12,2)
    else ''
  end
```

Comment: This code crashes on the example input `'20200814'`.

Comment: Just making some adjustment you can get what you want